# CUDA: Finding the N largest values of a sparse array

Tags: arrays, cuda

I have an array of a few million values stored on the global memory of the GPU. Most of them are zero, except for a few thousand. The values are the results of a computation on the device.

I want to find, say, the `1024` largest values as well as their indices, as fast as possible.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You create a array of 1024. You take the 1024 first non zero values, sort them and then you run your big array from the last point (i.e the 1024th of you array) and each time you pick a value which is higher than the first element of you array. You include it in your array of the highest value and remove the smallest and move the other one. It's a little fastidious but I don't see a faster way

Answer (score 5):

[This answer has been edited according to the comment by Robert Crovella]

For a simple approach to be implemented, I would suggest using `thrust::sort` or `thrust::sort_by_key` in descending order. Sorting in descending order can be achieved in both the cases by means of `thrust::greater<int>()`.

The simplest way is using `thrust::sort` in descending order so that you can sequentially access the sorted elements from the largest to the smallest.

If you want to retain a copy of the original data vector as well as the indices of the sorting procedure, you can use `thrust::sort_by_key` in descending order. Suppose that the array of your interest has `N` elements. You can create a sequence of increasing indices by `thrust::sequence`. In your case, the keys are the array of `N` elements, while the values are the array generated by `thrust::sequence`. Following the use of `thrust::sort_by_key` in descending order, the values array will contain the indices by which you can access the first largest elements.

Notice that you are actually interested in the case when your data array is *sparse*, so that you may be interested to sort only the non-vanishing values of the data array. In case you are interested to store only the non-vanishing values of the array, you do not need to create the indices vector `d_indices` by `thrust::sequence`, but it will be enough to store in that the indices of the non-vanishing data values. If you have already an array containing also the `0`'s, then you can extract the non-vanishing values before performing the sorting operations by `thrust::partition`.

Below is a complete example showing all the above approches.

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reverse.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>    
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct is_not_zero
{
    __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const int &x) { return x != 0; }
};

void main(void)
{

    const int N = 8;

    // --- Generate the data vector of random values on the host 
    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(N);
    thrust::generate(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), rand);

    // --- Move the data vector to the device
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec=h_vec;

    // --- Make two copies of the data vector
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec_copy=d_vec;
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec_another_copy=d_vec;

    // --- Push back some zero to test thrust::partition
    d_vec_another_copy.push_back(0);
    d_vec_another_copy.push_back(0);
    d_vec_another_copy.push_back(0);

    // --- Display the result
    for(int i = 0; i<N+3; i++)
        cout << d_vec_another_copy[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // --- Generate the indices vector
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_indices(N);
    thrust::sequence(d_indices.begin(), d_indices.end(), 0, 1);

    // --- Sort the indices vector by using the data vector as key in descending order
    thrust::sort_by_key(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), d_indices.begin(),thrust::greater<int>());

    // --- Display the result
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        int index = d_indices[i];
        cout << "Original: " << d_vec_copy[index] << " Sorted: " << d_vec[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // --- Use sort in descending order and forget the initial ordering
    thrust::sort(d_vec_copy.begin(), d_vec_copy.end(), thrust::greater<int>());

    // --- Display the result
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        cout << d_vec_copy[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // --- Use partition prior to sort to extract the non-vanishing elements in descending order
    thrust::partition(d_vec_another_copy.begin(), d_vec_another_copy.end(), is_not_zero());     
    thrust::sort(d_vec_another_copy.begin(), d_vec_another_copy.end(), thrust::greater<int>());

    // --- Display the result
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        cout << d_vec_another_copy[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;

    getchar();

}
```

Comment: If you know that 99+% of the values are zero, and you're only interested in non-zero values, it might also be interesting to see if a `thrust::partition` before the `thrust::sort` might be quicker (then sorting only the non-zero values).  And you can sort in descending order without the extra call(s) to `thrust::reverse`

Comment: Thankyou for these enlightening answers. One question though, can Thrust cooexist with my C code? You guessed it, I have never given Thrust a serious look.

Comment: What I meant is that I have used cudaMalloc CudMemcpy and so on. Would you recommend I throw all this away and start afresh with Thrust?

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks, Robert. I have revised my answer according to your comment.

Comment: @user1741137 Yes, CUDA Thrust can coesist with sequential code just like CUDA. Concerning your second question, it is difficult to say. If you are familiar with the C++ STL library, then learning Thrust should be easy and would provide you with a way to simultaneously achieve fast coding and codes. Perhaps if you are not familiar with CUDA, Thrust is an effective way to achieve speedups. Of course, handtuning applications directly with CUDA should lead you in principle to have even further speedups, but this requires you to have good CUDA programming skills.